# deserialization of json array with nested objects

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to deserialize a json file that has the following structure:
**String of objects(incidents) that contain nested string of objects(timeline) and additional data**

Input:

```
[


  {
    "id": "6590d474-00bc-4ec9-8386-5f23b834a4ac",
    "subject": "lists-webapp error rate jump to 15% an hour ago",
    "reporter": "erezp@google.com",
    "reportTime": "2017-04-13T07:04:52.742Z",
    "type": "incident",
    "status": "resolved",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "id": "05c0be2b-8441-4d89-bdff-5d98b3ba1358",
    "subject": "FYI Viewer success rate drop in Peru",
    "reporter": "dansh@google.com",
    "reportTime": "2017-03-24T11:55:59.870Z",
    "type": "incident",
    "status": "resolved",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "id": "1437f281-3da0-49da-b95e-c06bf9b83dfe",
    "subject": "Is App market down?",
    "reporter": "yaelra@google.com",
    "reportTime": "2017-04-13T12:57:17.864Z",
    "type": "incident",
    "status": "resolved",
    "__v": 2,
    "timeline": [
      {
        "dateTime": "2017-05-10T11:55:43.782Z",
        "updatedFieldName": "status",
        "newVal": "resolved",
        "oldVal": "investigating",
        "modifiedBy": "{\"email\":\"shaik@google.com\",\"displayName\":\" Kfir\",\"imageUrl\":\"https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-tSa00bTac8M/AAAAAAAAdAAI/AAAAAAAAA4s/pxvoRPGswGI/photo.jpg?sz=50\",\"accessToken\":\"\"}",
        "note": "Kfir did something",
        "_id": "5912ffbfea7fdb0010091b0a"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "5c45ed34-1637-44c0-90cc-6b5b818272d3",
    "subject": "Re: Users report phishing block on social media",
    "reporter": "idoi@google.com",
    "reportTime": "2017-04-14T14:41:37.798Z",
    "type": "incident",
    "status": "resolved",
    "__v": 1,
    "timeline": [
      {
        "dateTime": "2017-05-11T09:37:41.444Z",
        "updatedFieldName": "status",
        "newVal": "resolved",
        "oldVal": "reported",
        "modifiedBy": "{\"email\":\"elip@google.com\",\"displayName\":\" Ponyatovski\",\"imageUrl\":\"https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-MZ8WHdVK1NM/AAAAsAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAABM/sDo5Dj05bDk/photo.jpg?sz=50\",\"accessToken\":\"\"}",
        "_id": "591430e55ee8b90010030615"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "ff22ec2e-c717-4e28-b3a4-8c7c9c791248",
    "subject": "Unable to create new site from my account",
    "reporter": "doronbt@google.com",
    "reportTime": "2017-05-08T12:07:55.733Z",
    "type": "incident",
    "status": "resolved",
    "timeline": [
      {
        "updatedFieldName": "status",
        "modifiedBy": "doronbt@google.com",
        "newVal": "reported",
        "dateTime": "2017-05-08T12:07:55.733Z",
        "_id": "59105f9b1029b7001088c29e"
      },
      {
        "dateTime": "2017-05-10T13:38:20.229Z",
        "updatedFieldName": "status",
        "newVal": "resolved",
        "oldVal": "investigating",
        "modifiedBy": "{\"email\":\"elip@google.com\",\"displayName\":\" Ponyatovski\",\"imageUrl\":\"https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-MZ8WHdVK1NM/AAAsAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAABM/sDo5Dj05bDk/photo.jpg?sz=50\",\"accessToken\":\"\"}",
        "_id": "591317cc4dea7f000fdbb28d"
      }
    ],
    "__v": 2
  }
]
```

I've also created the relevant classes for Incident and Timeline:

```
public class Incident {
    private String reportTime;
    private String reporter;
    private String id;
    private String status;
    private String subject;
    private String __v;
    private String type;
    private Timeline[] timeline;
}

public class Timeline {
    private String updatedFieldName;
    private String newVal;
    private String oldVal;
    private String note;
    private String dateTime;
    private String modifiedBy;
}
```

I've managed to get a single incident with a single timeline object, but it does not work on multiple objects.
Maybe storing the timeline in an array is causing this issue?

Comment: "does not work" What is the expected and actual result?

Comment: I need a way to store in as a list/collection of objects that contain a nested collection.

I'm getting java.lang.NullPointerException.

Comment: post the exception